# How to xPath the mail from this particular XML?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

How to xPath the name.surname@mail.com from this particular XML (or at least the account AccountId):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-05-06T22:34:11" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-US">

    <pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://adress.com">
        <pc:DisplayName>Name, Surname</pc:DisplayName>
        <pc:AccountId>i:0#.f|membership|name.surname@mail.com</pc:AccountId>
        <pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType>
    </pc:Person>
</my:gr_SVs>
<my:ddl_tower>Tower</my:ddl_tower>
```

Comment: what do you mean `name.surname@mail.com` it is PCDATA of tag `pc:AccountId` ? what is desire output is your need?

Comment: Looks like Amrendra Kumar gave you valuable information. Why not [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) his answer

Comment: In your XML namespace conflict you can see `xmlns:pc` is declared two place with different url make it one or delete second one and xpath you written which has single inverted comma need to remove like `string(//pc:Person/pc:AccountId)`   see this link: http://xsltransform.net/pNEhB2B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like these:

If email is in last position [eg. in this case]:

```
tokenize(//pc:Person/pc:AccountId, '\|')[last()]
```

If you want to get element then use:

```
//pc:Person/pc:AccountId
```

Comment: Unfortunetely it doesnt work since it has ':'.
Currently my code is is:
xpath(xml(outputs('Compose')), 'string(//pc:Person/pc:AccountId')

Comment: xpath you written may not end with `'` single inverted comma. use `string(//pc:Person/pc:AccountId)` this